# How to find the next greater value generically in C++ for integers and floats?

Tags: c++, c++11, numbers, numeric-limits

I naively tried

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T a, T b){
   if(min==max){
      max += std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
   }
   // Do some other stuff
}
```

However I found out that epsilon returns 0 for integer types rather than 1 which seems like an oversight.   How do I solve the above including integers?

Comment: For integer `max` the next greater value is `max+1`. Before doing this, check that `max` is not already the maximum representable value.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
template<typename T>
T next(T v) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
        return v + 1;
    } else {
        return std::nextafter(v, std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity);   
    }
}
```

If you don't have `if constexpr`, then use overloading or template specialisation instead.

---

> ```
> max += std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
> ```

For many floating point values, `v + epsilon == v`. For many other values, it will skip neighbours.

Comment: C++11 doesn't have *constexpr if* m sorry !! Though it is a good answer